# Can't bind a subquery alias with outer query

Tags: sql-server, replace, subquery, alias

I am trying to replace a string in a select statement with the result of a subquery. I have an alias for my subquery "AS Replacement". However when I use replacement.firstname in the outer query, it cannot be found. Here is my query:

```
SELECT  REPLACE('##RecipientFirstName##', 'RecipientFirstName', replacement.firstname)
(
SELECT p.FirstName 
FROM dbo.Person p
WHERE p.PersonId = 16
)
AS replacement

 FROM dbo.MessageTypeGlobal mtg
WHERE mtg.MessageTypeGlobalId = 1
```

replacement.firstname in the first line is not found by intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the subquery into the Replace function...

```
SELECT  REPLACE('##RecipientFirstName##', 'RecipientFirstName',(SELECT p.FirstName FROM dbo.Person p WHERE p.PersonId = 16))    
 FROM dbo.MessageTypeGlobal mtg
WHERE mtg.MessageTypeGlobalId = 1
```